# Want to show $f(x)$ is continuous from the left

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x)=$
\begin{cases} 
      1 & x = 0 \\
      \sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\frac{x+|x|(1+x)}{x}\ & 
      x\neq0 
   \end{cases}

I want to show this function is continuous at $x_0 = 0$ from the left.

Comment: The left limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}f(x) = 0$ so I don't think your claim is right.